# Canvas layout with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, layout, canvas

I want to do layout into a canvas with javascript. This code is full screen. 
How do I get into canvas?

[image]

```js
$(".left.pane").resizable({
  handles: "e, w"
});
$(".right.pane").resizable({
  handles: "e, w"
});
$(".center.pane .inner .bottom").resizable({
  handles: "n, s"
});
```

```css
html, body { 
       margin: 0; 
       padding: 0
     }
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: moccasin;  
}
.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 21px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: fuchsia;
}
.inner-wrapper,
.center.pane .inner {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.pane {
    display: table-cell;
}
.left.pane {
   background-color: olivedrab; 
}
.center.pane {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.center.pane .inner .top,
.center.pane .inner .bottom{
    display: table-row;  
}
.center.pane .inner .top {
    background-color: lightcoral;   
}
.center.pane .inner .bottom {   
    background-color: orange;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.right.pane {
    background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="inner-wrapper">
       <div class="left pane">Left</div>
       <div class="center pane">
           <div class="inner">
               <div class="top">Center top</div>
               <div class="bottom">Center bottom</div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="right pane">Right</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried in canvas so far

Comment: I'm trying to edit code in the link.

Comment: canvas  { 
       margin: 0; 
       padding: 0
     } I have tried in this way but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQueryUI.resizable is not natively applicable to a canvas element.

To do the same thing in canvas you will have to do it manually. That's because canvas does not "remember" where it drew any individual rectangle and therefore canvas cannot individually move or resize any rectangle. What you must do is clear the entire canvas and redraw all the rectangles in their new positions and sizes.

1. Draw rectangles representing your div areas: `context.fillRect`
2. Listen for mouse events on the canvas: `addEventListener('mousedown'...etc`
3. "Manually" resize the rectangles in response to mouse events:

   - Save each rectangles properties in an object: `var rect1={x:,y:,width:,height:}`
   - On mousedown, hit-test each rectangle. If hit, flag that rectangle as resizing. Hit test algorithm: `var isHit = mouseX>rect.x && mouseX<rect.x+rect.width && mouseY>rect.y && mouseY<rect.y+rect.height`
   - On mousemove, clear the entire canvas and redraw all rectangles. Resize the flagged rectangle by the distance the mouse has dragged: `rect.width+=(mouseX-startingMouseX); rect.height+=(mouseY-startingMouseY);` Presumably you will also have to resize the other rectangles to fit with the rectangle that is expanding/shrinking.
   - On mouseup, stop the resizing.